# Why is this allowed in If statements in various languages?

Tags: if-statement, comparison, variable-assignment

In various programming and scripting languages like C and PHP, `if`  statements use the following convention:

```
if ( variable == 1 ) { do something }
```

As far as I know, every language that follows this convention also allows:

```
if ( variable = 1 ) { do something }
```

This is a not too uncommon mistake even a seasoned programmer can make.  Rather than a comparison, it is an assignment, which will (almost) always be successful and return 1, which is a non-zero number, meaning `true`.  The only time I think this would fail is if the variable isnt in scope or possibly a type mismatch.  Yes, all its looking for 1 or 0, true of false and the comparison itself is irrelevant.  However, I assume a compariison makes up 99.9999% of these `if` statements. Is there a reason a comparison isnt required?  Why is this allowed?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If assignment is an expression, which it is in such languages, there would be no reason for it not to be allowed in that context, unless a special rule was implemented to disallow it. It's commonly used to check for null pointers resulting from assignment, or combined with a comparison operator to do more complex check on what was assigned.

Comment: In fact, I believe that use case was actually used as part of the justification for adding an assignment expression operator `:=` to Python.

Comment: Does python allow if (x = 1)....?

Comment: @Tarik No, Python requires `if (x := 1)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate I suppose I understand the rationale behind your comment, I just dont like it.  :P  I would suspect this error must account for innumerable and countless hours wasted in debugging.  If you make it an answer, Ill accept it.